# URL keeps on loading which is executed using php curl

Tags: php

I am working on academic project for ecommerce which is about online book renting using PHP. I am making sure that user can only view rented book pdf file only after visiting site to do so I have use cloudfile.io which generate link for sharing file. I can use embed tag for adding file to my page but  I don't want user to see file link so I use  curl function to display file in my page but it keeps on loading.

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloudfil.es/0mU5B5e0eX3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I have tried to use headers for displaying pdf file this also doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it keeps on loading"? How is this isolated piece of code you have provided called/used?

Comment: when i open this file in my localhost one circle keeps on rotating in a blank white page

Comment: Is the PDF valid? Is it a file you have downloaded from that site? The file in your example above does not appear to be a PDF at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear anything already sent to the browser then send the correct headers so that the browser knows that a PDF is coming.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://cloudfil.es/0mU5B5e0eX3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

while (ob_get_level() !== 0) {ob_end_clean();}
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="YourFileNameHere.pdf"');
echo $data;
```

Comment: how can i get file name

Comment: Give it any name you'd like. Or use whatever name may be associated with the file you are retrieving. In your example above the name appears to be Intrusion which sounds like a reasonable name.

Comment: i think you are not getting it

https://cloudfile.es/0mU5B5e0eX3 this is the link of file generated in cloud storage  I want this file to be viewed by user who have paid rent for it for security purpose I don't want link to be visible so I use php curl for executing this file in another page but  it is not working. user should only view this file by opening that specific page without downloading it

Comment: admin explicitly add link while adding book to the database and user have to pay for renting file after that user can view the e book using the link so i don't want to expose link

Comment: I know and understand what you are trying to do. If you know the name of the document/book/whatever use that name or make something up. It really doesn't matter. My point, in the comments to your original question, is that the example you posted is NOT actually a PDF.